# Is there a way to transfer a Skype for Business call from the mobile app to the desktop and visiversa?

Tags: lync, skype-for-business-2016

In the past, I have heard others talk about how they liked a Lync feature, which made it possible to switch a call from being on the desktop to a mobile phone and back again. Now that I have access to Skype for Business 2016, I'm looking for that feature.